# How to update an object of an array in indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

For example I have an array of objects:

```
const arrayOfPersons = [
    { name: 'Alex', ssn: 123, children: [
        { name: 'Tom', yearOfBirth: '2023', isHappy: true },
        { name: 'Emma', yearOfBirth: '2012', isHappy: true }
    ]},
    { name: 'John', ssn: 234, children: [
        { name: 'Harry', yearOfBirth: '2003', isHappy: true },
        { name: 'Eva', yearOfBirth: '2020', isHappy: true },
        { name: 'Henry', yearOfBirth: '1999', isHappy: true }
    ]}
];
```

Database was created with this code:

```
const request = indexedDB.open(nameOfDB, 1);

request.onerror = (event) => {
    console.error(`Database error: ${event.target.errorCode}`);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
    const db = event.target.result;
    const objectStore = db.createObjectStore(nameOfObjectStore, { keyPath: "ssn" });
};
```

I need to upgrade the 'isHappy' property of a certain child. What is the best way to do it?

Here I get a person via get() method and then iterate through all his children.

```
    const request = indexedDB.open(nameOfDB, 1);

    request.onerror = (event) => {
        console.error(`Database error: ${event.target.errorCode}`);
    };

    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        const db = event.target.result;

        const personObjectStore = db
            .transaction(nameOfObjectStore, "readwrite")
            .objectStore(nameOfObjectStore);

        const getPersonRequest = personObjectStore.get(123);

        getPersonRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
            const person = event.target.result;

            person.children.forEach( (child) => {
                if (child.name == 'Emma') {
                    child.isHappy = false;
                }
            });

            personObjectStore.put(person).onsuccess = (event) => {
                console.log('successfully updated');
            };
        }
    };
```

It works but it doesn't look very efficient.

Also I have another question. Does put() method rewrite all object or update only modified entries? My actual DB I am going to work on contains lots of huge arrays and those arrays contain lots of data.

Comment: It would be better to move children into a separate table. Then you can look up the child directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works but it doesn't look very efficient.

Given how you're storing the data, that's probably as efficient as you'll get. Database experts would probably say that you should flatten out the data so that children are in their own store, with a compound index like [parent_ssn, name] and then you can do a direct lookup for just that record.

> Does put() method rewrite all object or update only modified entries?

It replaces the entire record. That's another reason to consider storing your data in a decomposed form. But... remember that modern computers and storage are pretty darn fast, so don't optimize prematurely. Values smaller than few hundred kilobytes are probably fine to update atomically, but you should do performance testing on representative hardware or gather metrics from the wild to inform these decisions.